# calling javascript function from <select> onchange

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to call a javascript function from the onchange attribute of the `select` tag ! My issue is that I am passing the name attribute of the select to the function which always go null.

```
<body>


<form action="" method="post">
<select name="slct" id="name" onchange="rohan('measurement_conversion', '<?php echo isset($_POST["slct"])?$_POST["slct"]:"null" ?>')">
<option value="yes" selected="selected"> yes </option>
<option value="nopes"> nopes </option>
<option value="may be"> May be </option>
<option value="dont know"> dont know </option>
</select>
</form>

<div id="abc">
</div>


</body>
```

And here my javascript function

```
<script>

function rohan(var1, var2)
{

    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML=var1 + "            " + var2;
}

</script>
```

It always prints null..
Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <select name="slct" id="name" onchange="rohan(this.value)">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option value="yes" selected="selected"> yes </option>
            <option value="nopes"> nopes </option>
            <option value="may be"> May be </option>
            <option value="dont know"> dont know </option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    function rohan(value)
    {
        //you can get the value from arguments itself
        alert(value);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is run on the server before JavaScript is ever run in the browser. It doesn't get re-evaluated when the user changes the selected item.

Comment: So what will be the solution ?

Comment: Code that reacts to user changes needs to either (a) be written in JavaScript, not PHP... or (b) use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

No put in tag HTML attribute javascript, `onchange` is better in the script:

```
<script>
    var b=document.getElementById('name');
        b.onchange=function (){
        var a=document.getElementById('name').value;
        console.log(a);
    }
</script>
```